# Default font sizes with wxWidgets on OSX

Tags: macos, fonts, wxwidgets

I've noticed that my wxWidgets application does not follow the native font sizes on OSX. They are typically too big and also the same font size is used for all widgets, which does not seem to be the case by native default.

I've tried to handle this myself by applying fonts to the top level windows. I've used TinkerTool to read the defaults (should be done automatically of course) and create corresponding fonts, for example using `wxFont(wxFontInfo(12).FontName("Helvetica")` but it does not render the same as other, native applications.

Does anyone know of a good method to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any examples when wxWidgets controls don't use the same fonts as the native controls, please report any occurrences of this as bugs in the [wxWidgets Trac](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/), especially if this is using 2.9.4 (old 2.8 versions use Carbon and are hopeless on modern OS X anyhow). But without any concrete examples I can't really help with this.

As for the font sizes, I think you might be looking for [wxWindow::SetWindowVariant()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#acd955418c336e73b3e32cadf1ca46e29) which allows to use smaller versions of the controls which is rather common in OS X UI.

Comment: Thanks, SetWindowVariant was the trick! It seems like all (?) native applications use a smaller window variant. For example, open the builtin text editor and open the settings dialog. Compare with the "widgets" sample in wxWidgets. All widgets and fonts are bigger in the sample application. But by setting wxWINDOW_VARIANT_SMALL to the main frame they look very much the same to me.